# Dropbox couldn't find resource trusted-certs.jks

Tags: java, ssl, dropbox

I am trying to just normally use the dropbox java api in a bukkit plugin but for some reason it just won't work. Here is the code for the dropbox part:

```
public DbxClient client;
final String APP_KEY = "<REDACTED>";
final String APP_SECRET = "<REDACTED>";

DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig(
        "JavaTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);
String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();

public void geturl(Player p){
    p.sendMessage(authorizeUrl);
}

public void authorize(String code){
    try{
        DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
        String accessToken = authFinish.accessToken;
        client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);
    }
    catch(DbxException e){}

}

public void upload(String fullpath){
    try {
        File inputFile = new File(fullpath);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile(fullpath,
                DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    }
    catch(DbxException| IOException e){}
```

Anyway, the geturl works fine, it returns an url that I click and copy the code that I get. I then proceed to running authorize with that code as an argument and I get this error:

```
org.bukkit.event.EventException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:294) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:501) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:483) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.chat(PlayerConnection.java:882) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:832) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInChat.a(PacketPlayInChat.java:28) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.PacketPlayInChat.handle(PacketPlayInChat.java:47) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:84) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.NetworkManager.channelRead0(NetworkManager.java:204) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:98) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:337) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:323) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:173) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:337) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:323) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:173) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:337) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:323) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:337) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:323) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler.channelRead(ReadTimeoutHandler.java:149) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:337) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:323) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:785) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:100) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:480) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:447) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:341) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at net.minecraft.util.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Couldn't find resource "trusted-certs.jks"
    at com.dropbox.core.http.SSLConfig.loadKeyStore(SSLConfig.java:312) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.http.SSLConfig.createSSLSocketFactory(SSLConfig.java:186) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.http.SSLConfig.<clinit>(SSLConfig.java:65) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.prepRequest(StandardHttpRequestor.java:166) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:89) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.http.StandardHttpRequestor.startPost(StandardHttpRequestor.java:23) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.startPostNoAuth(DbxRequestUtil.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.doPostNoAuth(DbxRequestUtil.java:271) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxWebAuthHelper.finish(DbxWebAuthHelper.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxWebAuthNoRedirect.finish(DbxWebAuthNoRedirect.java:84) ~[?:?]
    at com.czaarek99.antidupe.files.FileExplorer.authorize(FileExplorer.java:197) ~[?:?]
    at com.czaarek99.antidupe.files.FileExplorer.onFileExplore(FileExplorer.java:141) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_67]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:292) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.9-R0.2-16-g37c7969-b3105jnks]
    ... 31 more
```

Obviiously the important part is where it says caused by, how can I fix this?

Comment: I removed your app key and secret from the code above, but you should probably delete the app and create a new one just to be safe.

Comment: Decided upon not using this app/api anyway, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar trouble when trying to use webAuth.finish(code) to get access code from Dropbox server. the library requires "JKS" keystore which is absent in android platform.